# python validate input with decorator for functions with varying inputs

Tags: python

I have many functions that all expected `config` as a parameter but vary with regards to other parameters. I would like to validate `config`. I wrote another function for this, but seems a decorator might be a cleaner solution:

```py
def validate_config(config):
    if config not in [1,2,3]:
        raise ValueError("config is expected to be 1, 2 or 3")

def f1(config, b):
    validate_config(config)
    pass

def f2(a, config):
    validate_config(config)
    pass
```

Comment: you throw an exception but you don't catch it anywhere. Is the program supposed to crash when config doesn't pass the validation?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, raising an exception is not the same as crashing. The functions `f1` and `f2` are not called anywhere in the code, so the exception will not be raised anyway, but they will obviously be called somewhere in the code not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need get function paraments name at runtime,
Fortunately, python can do this in easy way

use module `inspect`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults

```
import functools
import inspect


def validate_config(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        ba = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        ba.apply_defaults()
        print("config:", ba.arguments["config"])
        return func(*ba.args, **ba.kwargs)

    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, func)


@validate_config
def foo(config, b):
    pass


foo("this_is_config", 123)
```

But it's not a good idea to rely on parameter names